# CSS: Responsive background image height

Tags: html, background-image, css

I'm using this CSS:

```
.wrap {
    max-width:1400px;
    min-width:768px;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat scroll;
    background-position: center top;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

To center an image and scale it based on window size, stopping the scaling at 768px. I can't display the bottom part of the image when the window is at a larger size (it works fine when the window is minimized). When I change the height of the `.image` class to more than 600px, it breaks the image scaling...

Here's a demo of the problem:
http://jrbaldwin.com/css_issue/

Comment: Try `background-position: center center;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: contain;` on the `.image` class and `min-width: 100%;` for the `.wrap` class - looks about right to me in FF.

Comment: your demo link is broken!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not scaling because the height is staying fixed. For example, set the .image height to 1000px. It has to enlarge the image to cover 1000px so it fills the entire 1000px height at all time, no matter what width the image is.

Possibly try:

> background-size: 100%;
>   background-repeat: no-repeat;

Answer (score 1):

Building on @jtlowe's answer, couldn't you achieve the right effect by using `background-size: contain` instead?

Since you're already firmly in the CSS3 domain, you can optionally create a media query that uses `cover` in smaller size windows.

Comment: Yes, but once the width is large enough to "contain" the image, the image may no longer scale up.

Comment: This might not be an issue here though, because the width of the container has a max-width of 1400px;

Comment: @jtlowe: Indeed, my thought exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Use background-size: contain instead of cover.

Answer (score 1):

Try this styles:

```
.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  max-height: 1000px;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

The main idea is to use "contain" property 
More information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images